# Как получить разность двух дат, если они занесены в один INPUT диапазоном?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Подскажите пожалуйста, как получить разность диапазона дат внесенных в один INPUT?

Например = 09.12.2020 - 10.12.2020, как разбить это парсером, вычесть разницу и вывести ajax ответом рядом с полем.

```
    <p><b>График:</b><br>
   <input type="text" name="grafik" id="graphik-id">
  </p>
```

backend на php, но как я понял тут можно JS пройтись по INput'у

Comment: input обычный текст, в котором вводят дату через дефис

Answer (score 0):

Как-то так

```js
let range = '09.12.2020 - 10.12.2020';

let diff = range.split('-').map(item=>new Date(item.trim().split('.').reverse())).reduce((acc, item) => item - acc);

console.log(diff); // разница в миллисекундах
console.log(diff/86400000);// дней
console.log(new Date(diff));
```